# How to get last inserted row from a datatable

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using [datatables](https://datatables.net) plugin to create a datatable. I've put a button to add new rows. The new inserted row can be anywhere depends on which column the table is sorted by. I need to set an event to the button inside the row once it is inserted. So I have to get the last inserted row to do so. But I can't find a way. I've tried below but it's not working. `index()` does not returning exact index where the row really is.

```
var row = table.row.add({...});
row.draw();
var tr = $('#datatable tbody tr').get(row.index());
```

Please help. Your answer is kindly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't find a way to this using any plugin's provided function. But thank God there's a workaround.

> Flag the inserted row in column rendering function. For example, I append a tag

```
datatable = $('#datatable').DataTable({columns : [{render : function(){... <last/> ...}}]});
```

> On inserting new row, insert it with a data that indicate the flag inclusion. Get the row by the flag. And then remove the flag.

```
datatable.row.add({...}).draw();
var row = $('last').parents('tr');
$('last').remove();
```

> For any other case which don't need to edit the `<tr>` explicitly, get the index of last inserted row. Get the datatable row and update the data. Set column render function to render the updated row accordingly.

```
var i = datatable.rows().count() - 1;
var data = datatable.row(i).data();
datatable.row(i).data(changeSomething(data)).draw();
```

> And to remove the row

```
datatable.row(i).remove().draw();
```

Answer (score 2):

> Take length of table and `-1` and that number is the `index` of last
>   `tr`

```
var lastRowIndex = $('#datatable tr').length -1;
```

Comment: +1 thank you for your answer. but sorry sir. it's not working when the new row is in the middle. i've put my own answer

Comment: Okay good luck then. i just wanted to provide the simple solution. happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

New rows will be appended onto the end of the row list, so you can do something like this

```
table.row(table.rows().count()-1)
```

See fiddle [here](http://live.datatables.net/nizoxodi/1/edit).

Comment: thank you for your answer. in my case there's a popup form to fill in first before row is inserted. so new row can also be in the middle

Comment: yep, that example I posted puts the row into the middle of the table - but it still returns the last row added. Have you looked at the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

get the last or most recent row data directly from the datatable object

```
let last_row_index = datatable.data().length -1;

let last_row_data = datatable.rows(last_row_index).data();
```

(because a user can sort it in anyway thus a CSS method would return the sorting of the user and not the real last row data)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column to track this going forward to track:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table ADD DateInserted DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Now you can find the last row(s) inserted by simply by using the below query:

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT *, r = RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DateInserted DESC)   
   FROM dbo.table) SELECT * FROM x WHERE r = 1;
```